# How do I plot time series data by week and year?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple time series dataframe('cats'). Transactions by year and week. I just want a line chart with the year and week in the axis.

```
    year    week    transactions
0   2013    25      1824
1   2013    26      1876392
2   2013    27      2048913
3   2013    28      2060043
4   2013    29      1864779
5   2013    30      1844886
6   2013    31      2089084
7   2013    32      2017478
8   2013    33      1927819
9   2013    34      1965046
```

I can get the line to work here doing this, but it only plots vs the index

`plt.plot(cats['total_sales'])`

[image]

But when I try to add an axis something like this happens

`plt.plot(cats['year'],cats['total_sales'])`

[image]

Comment: The problem is that your x-data is just year. So in your plot all the y-values for certain year are located in on position - at 2013, at 2014 and so on. Make a proper x-data with date values based on the weeknumber and year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a column of proper datetimes from your year and week number:

```
# %U assumes Monday as first day of the week. Use %W for Sunday
cats['week_yr'] = pd.to_datetime(cats['year'].astype(str) + ' ' + cats['week'].astype(str) + ' 1',
                                format='%Y %U %w')
```

Then you can do:

```
cats.plot.line(x='week_yr', y='transactions')
```

And get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `plt.xticks`

```
x = range(len(cats['total_sales']))
plt.plot(x, cats['total_sales'])
plt.xticks(x, zip(cats['year'], cats['week']))
```